# Best practices for building multiple declaration file formats

Tags: typescript

I'm working from JavaScript files with `checkJs`, and because of this, I'm often distracted with info related to the export of actual code, but my interest is mostly on declaration files.

I'm trying to understand the interplay of module formats like ESM or CJS and declaration files.

While different `module` settings can, I understand, create different export formats when converting from TypeScript to JavaScript, it seems to me that it doesn't work as an approach to convert a single source file into two different *declaration* formats in the hopes that the declaration files would reflect the structure of the files *after* they get converted into the said format.

So if I specify CommonJS as a `module` format for an ESM-style file, it will export code into CommonJS, but it will apparently indicate the declaration file with details on it coming from an ESM export.

My declaration files are looking the same regardless of what `module` I choose I guess because the source file is the same. Since [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html#packagejson-exports-imports-and-self-referencing) mention, "the CommonJS entrypoint and the ES module entrypoint each needs its own declaration file", it seems the above is all pointing me toward the need to not only have one declaration file built from my source file but also one built by targeting another export format file (e.g., a CommonJS output from ESM) so I have two different types of declaration files (reflecting each format) which I can indicate in `exports`.

But with a build step, typing info can be lost, so I can't benefit from `checkJs` run on such generated code (surely, very few modify their built files after the fact to get them to adhere to typing; you may say `checkJs` isn't important if the build step is trustworthy, but will a faithful declaration file always be built from such a build file?). Is there a best practice here?